# How to show MessageBox notification when agent rejects call in Workspace Desktop Edition custom module?

Tags: c#, genesys, workspace-desktop-edition

I need to show a notification while agent rejects voice call incoming from customer to his WDE.
Is there any interaction or chain of commands which execute when that happens?

The problem isn't showing the MessageBox, the problem is to catch the moment when voice call is rejected.

I tried to look for this information while debugging Events which execute while any voice call is rejected, but to no avail.

Events which execute while call is rejected are EventRinging and twice EventPartyReleased, i suspect that this information could be somewhere in EventPartyReleased, but i couldn't find it.

I also tried looking for some chain of commands, but found only InteractionVoiceAnswerCall, which executes when agent answers the call, not rejects it.